# How to deprive the vote in muc room via api

Tags: ejabberd

What command helps to do that via ejabberd rest-api?
From xmpp-client log such command sending:

```
<iq id="60fe7dd6-82c3-49de-a5a1-f1f71bce6e92" to="chat_room@conference.example.com" type="set">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin">
        <item nick="user_block@example.com" role="visitor"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

Ejabberd version is 20.xx. And i want to say this opportunity works great at swift client connected to our ejabberd service. Just click 'revoke voice' and that user becomes 'visitor' and can't send messages.
But I can't do that even via xmpp client smack sdk:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
.setXmppAddressAndPassword(JidCreate.entityBareFrom("user1@example.com"), "123")
.setHost("example.com")
.setPort(5222)
.build();
AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login();
MultiUserChatManager mucManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
MultiUserChat muc = mucManager.getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom("chat_room@conference.example.com"));
muc.revokeVoice(Resourcepart.from("User2"));
```

an Exception after trying:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPP error reply received from chat_room@conference.example.com: XMPPError: not-allowed - cancel [Changing role/affiliation is not allowed]
```

But 'user1@example.com' has admin permission and room 'chat_room@conference.example.com' has 'moderated' option in true.

Does anyone know how to do that via api for example via send_stanza?

Comment: Update your question explaining this: What ejabberd version did you install? What mod_muc configuration do you have? What chapter of https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html do you want to perform?

Comment: The question was updated. I want to perform 'revokevoice' option of xep-0045  https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#revokevoice.

Answer (score 0):

> `<item nick="user_block@example.com" role="visitor"/>`

Are you sure this works? This tells ejabberd that the nick to revoke voice is "user_block@example.com", but that is not a nick, it's the user JID. How can that work?

The example in
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#revokevoice
shows that te nick is... a nick:

> `<item nick='thirdwitch' role='visitor'/>`

---

I tried with my desktop Jabber client, Tkabber, and it sends the occupant's nick in the nick field.

When I send the occupant JID in the nick field, then I get the same error message that you mentioned.

I don't know about the library and language that your are using, but this smells wrong:

> `muc.revokeVoice(Resourcepart.from("User2"));`

I imagine here you must provide the occupant's nick, and that may not be the resource part of the occupant JID.

---

For example, when my client joins the room, it sends this stanza:

```
<presence id='71:576798'
    from='user2@example.com/tka1'
    to='chat_room@conference.example.com/troller'>
  <show>xa</show>
  <status>Busysss</status>
</presence>
```

Occupant full JID: "user2@example.com/tka1", which has as resource: "tka1", and joins the room with the nick "troller".

In this example, when a room admin wants to revoke voice to that occupant, the admin client must send this:

```
<iq id='50:565577'
    type='set'
    to='chat_room@conference.example.com'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item nick='troller'
    role='visitor'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Comment: Thanks for expanded answer!  
`muc.revokeVoice(Resourcepart.from("User2"))` works great after user1 joining room:  
`muc.join(Resourcepart.from("user1@example.com"));`  
So, I've solved this problem by smack library.  
As for using nick, participant can have a nick like his jid, and so it uses as param of stanza command and it works great.  

And what about change role via api trough send_stanza command. Is it possible or not. Which condiitons are necessary in ejabberd.yml for this.

Comment: There is no API for changing the role, only to change the affiliation.